# Where can I play Hearts online?

Tags: online, hearts

I would like to play against other people.

Can't seem to find any sites.

Answer (score 4):

[Yahoo! Games](http://uk.play.yahoo.com/games/login?game=Hearts) has Hearts. Actually I originally signed up for a Yahoo account so I could play Hearts.

Comment: cool thanks. wow, looks so old though, u know any newer websites?

Comment: do you find that when you play, it keeps booting you out of games? I logged in and probably was booted out of 10-15 games before I could play

Answer (score 2):

I used to play mostly Bridge and occasionally Hearts on [pogo.com](http://www.pogo.com/).  Again it's a site that's been around for many years, though!

Answer (score 1):

[PlayOK](http://www.playok.com/) is pretty good and uses almost-standard rules of Black Lady Hearts.  It runs on Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can play Hearts now on [Board Game Arena](http://boardgamearena.com/#!gamepanel?game=hearts). There are also many other board and card games available.

If you want to know why I recommend BGA, please have a look at [my post on another question here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/8778/2500). There are many reasons to join BGA community, mostly:

> 1. Many great games.
> 2. Technology - web based
> 3. Both live & asynchronous play
> 4. Table system
> 5. Community
>
>    - Reputation
>    - Feedback
> 6. Ease of use