# Telepresence Board Games

Tags: online, board-game-adaptations

I was wondering if anyone has had any success in playing board games with remote players? I have a few friends that live too far away to make a regular game night with however they really enjoy board games.

We were thinking that we could have a screen for the remote people, a webcam on the local players, and an overhead one on the play area.

Comment: Possible duplicate here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-with-someone-in-another-location (although it may be a little outdated by now)

Answer (score 1):

### Try Diplomacy!

I have found [Diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_(game)) to be an amazing solution to this sort of  issue. Originally played by mail in the 60s (famously known as US President John F. Kennedy's favorite game), Diplomacy maintains a strong remote gaming presence, but now in an online setting. The original game has 7 players but they have variants with down to 2 players, or up to 36.

### HOW IT APPLIES TO YOU

You can all get on with your buddies and set the game up to have 15 minute phases between moves (if everyone presses ready, it automatically processes to save time) and you can play for 3-5 hours to make for a fun **game night** that way while voice calling or in-game chatting (be careful of your volume when someone screams after a backstab hahaha).

Or you can set the phases to 24 hours so people have more time to play and can focus 10 minutes everyday on it. (best for people with busy schedules like me)

Just make sure you make these games private as the community is very good and playing with friends is considered "cheating" as it may provide you with reasons outside of the game to remain loyal to someone / an alliance.

### SUGGESTED WEBSITES

Modern Minimalist Interface, No Variants, Medium Community, free, no ranking system what-so-ever:

[Backstabbr](http://backstabbr.com)

Easy-To-Read Interface, Some Variants, Large Community, free but you can donate, competitive point system:

[Web Diplomacy](http://webdiplomacy.net)

Easy-To-Read Interface, Most Variants, Small Community, free, point system:

[Variant Diplomacy](http://vdiplomacy.net) (Made by Creators of WebDiplomacy as a 'experimental website')

Modern Easy-To-Read Interface, Very Few Variants, Large Community, paid subscription for extra variants and other features, point system:

[Play Diplomacy](http://playdiplomacy.com)

I personally used Backstabbr until the frequent CDs from online players got to me. I am a proud WebDiplomacy user now. I like the interface of PlayDiplomacy but I do not entertain the idea of a paid subcription for "premium" features.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is online game services like [Boardgame Arena](https://en.boardgamearena.com/)

It's available and cross-compatible on phones, tablets, game systems and browsers making it very accessible for a variety of individuals.

The available library is very good and it plays pretty well (However I haven't tried everything quite yet...)

Answer (score 0):

A very good way to play tabletop games online, is Tabletop simulator. Unfortunately, this is a paid game, so you can't play it for free. I have it myself, and I have enjoyed multiple awesome game sessions with friends. There are a few official boardgames available as add-on, and a massive amount of mods made by other players, most of them very playable. I believe they offer a bundle for multiple keys for the game, but I think you can find it fairly cheap online.