# Where can I play Carcassonne or Colonists of Catan online?

Tags: catan, carcassonne, online

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boardgaming Online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online)

I want to play Carcassonne or Colonists (Settlers) of Catan online, either against other people, or against a computer opponent.

I want to improve my skills so that I won't finish last when I play with my friends.
Where can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brettspielwelt](http://brettspielwelt.com/) hosts Carcassonne and Settlers (as well as a number of other games) which you can play against other people, and [Catan.com](http://www.catan.com/) hosts Settlers, again against other people.

For playing against the computer, or other people, [JCloisterZone](http://jcloisterzone.com/en/) is a great, free, downloadable clone of Carcassonne.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPhone/iPad there are "official" Carcassonne and Catan clients there. Carcassonne allows for Internet play through using your Game Center account. It will also match you up with random opponents or allow for local wi-fi play. Catan does not have internet play but does have fairly decent computer opponents. Both versions have upgrades for expansions, tile sets, etc. The Catan client is supposed to be getting the Cities and Knights expansion soon.

Just do a search in the App Store for each one to find out more.